# Blender 2.8 and Duplicate Questions

Tags: discussion, moderation

On the [stack overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) it is said that "questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl." and "that you optimize for pearls, not sand". So with that context here is my question.

The public beta release of Blender 2.8 is looming, and I anticipate a lot of "Duplicate" and or "Similar" questions coming in that will have much different answers now than in the past because of the keyboard remapping, menu and interface changes etc. so, how will the moderation policies adapt to accommodate or work around this?

Comment: What kinds of changes are you thinking of? I don't think asking how to do \$thing in 2.8 would necessarily be considered a duplicate of asking how to do \$thing in 2.7x.

Comment: @gandalf3 Well that's exactly what I was asking. Thank you for clearing that up.