# Should questions that need a new answer for 2.8 be flagged somehow?

Tags: discussion

I came across an answer that would have worked for my question, except the new layout in 2.8 has moved that item and so the answer was useless. I could ask a new question - but then, people who google the question like I did are probably going to be directed to the old question, and it won't help them. Also I've always found it difficult to effectively search for what I need on the Blender SE, and so I would hate to mess up this question's relatively good searchability.

So I daydreamed about some happy way to flag questions like this for updating. I know that only a small minority of users would so flag, but maybe that would still look after a big chunk of the issue. Do you think there is any good way to do this?

This is the question that led to this: [Viewing normals in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/100199/7548)

Comment: You could flag, but who will update-answer them? Getting rep on new questions is hard enough these days, on older ones even more so. Judging by the amount of duplicates we get I assume most users aren't bothering searching much anyway. SE search engine doesn't help either, so I suspect incentive to post new answers on old questions is very low. It is probably more productive to answer on new questions  that get more visibility. Many answers for 2.7# are still valid anyway, base workflow and principles still work, save for some shortcut key changes which are easy to overcome.

Comment: Also see Also see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/blender-2-8-is-going-beta-what-now which I think this question is mostly a duplicate of.

Answer (score 9):

#### No

Flags are for things that are bad enough they need to be dealt with quicker or differently then could be using the tools given from the [privileges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Take a look at the type of flags you can cast:

[image: flagging dialog]
PS would you flag the question or the non 2.8x answer?

Right away we know the first three flags will not work. Its not *spam*, *rude*, or it is *not an answer*. Or on the question side, *should be closed* and *a duplicate...* do not work either.

We're down to just "*very low quality*" and "*in need of moderator intervention*"
Hopefully the post is not LQ, low quality, but if it is that is a different issue so this flag should not be used to mark non 2.8x content either.

The custom flag "*in need of moderator intervention*" is **not** meant for this either. If I were to handle a flag that said "this answer does not work for 2.8" I would decline your flag with the either of these two reasons:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

So what would be the best thing to do? **Add the 2.8 answer yourself.** Now in some case its ok to just edit the existing answer and add the 2.8x changes, but for some answers that would be extensively different add a new answer.

So you don't want to answer it yourself, or at least right now. then what? Add a link to the question in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97982/2-8-answers). The [2.8 Answers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97982/2-8-answers) room is an experiment where hopefully we can collect and get "fixed" some of these non 2.8 questions.

Comment: I'd go against editing for anything other than very minor changes. Going forward as an actively developed software Blender is expected to continue changing, and answers would potentially evolve into some hard to follow Frankenstein with each version. Whenever possible a new answer is probably preferable, including updated screenshots

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos completely agree. Was thinking for minor things like shortcut changes, or [this example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/47839/revisions).