# Suggestion: Tend towards Merge instead of Close As Duplicate

Tags: discussion

I'll make it quick.

Problems:  Correct documentation for Blender is a moving target, moreso nowadays.  It is desirable for old answers to get updated to reflect the new UI, new parameter names, etc.  We get some questions that get closed as duplicates with links to old answers.

Suggestion:  If we identify a question that has an old duplicate we more or less leave it alone for a while, suggesting any old duplicates as merge targets in the comments.  Let the new question gather answers, and merge good answers into whatever is the better formed question.

Maybe there are limits to the merge system I don't understand, but I look forward to discussion.

It would also go some way towards reducing friction with new users.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/should-questions-that-need-a-new-answer-for-2-8-be-flagged-somehow

Comment: The idea is to reduce information scattering. By "allowing new questions to gather answers" for newer versions instead of updating "cannonical questions" or adding new answers to them, we start having related information about the same issue scattered all over the place making it harder to find and follow. Closing as a duplicate of a well know answers makes them gather votes and become "more familiar" and easier to find in the future.

Comment: There are already  plenty of very detailed,  we'll thought out,  and clearly explained answers that show the solutions on outdated interfaces, but that can, and should be updated. Accumulating  new redundant (and mostly incomplete) answers instead, will make this site less valuable as a resource. The fact that answers are editable, and therefore updatable, is this site's greatest asset, in my opinion.

Comment: Duplicates are not a "bad" thing. Blender changes quickly now, and it will continue to do so for the [foreseeable future](https://code.blender.org/2020/02/release-planning-2020-2025/) Let the dupes be dupes, and send users to the ones that are useful. [Don't edit](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/blender-2-8-is-going-beta-what-now) old 2.7X questions just to change the answers, write your own if it's really needed. New users come and go, most won't care to learn how the site works. The ones who do will contribute something worthwhile.

Comment: @Timaroberts I agree with most of what you wrote except the "don't edit" part. Plenty of answers can be made better and can be updated while being still useful for those who still use the older versions, or don't have the hardware to run to newer ones. Most functions have not changed, they are just in different coordinates of the interface or have no keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Ok.  To be clear I'm not saying "always this, never that", I more just want to open up a third possibility.  It may be that we find some questions once in a while that it would be better to merge new answers into, I'm just throwing the idea out there.  We should at least have a rough idea of how it could work.
Here's a good post I read the other day.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question

Comment: @susu I understand, I should say don't edit *to change the answer* but if needed to add supplemental information where it makes to, use sound judgement. Looking at a few of my own old answers, it would make more sense to say "now this is here..." instead of of an entire rewrite of the answer.